# Vue sort object key values descending by english string number

Tags: vue.js

I have above data for dropdown. This list is in random order, I would like to display the list in descending order by the key values (One, Three, Five, ...).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {
      Abc: "Abc",
      Thg: "Thg",
      Acb: "AAb"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <option v-for="(item, key) in data" :value="key" v-bind:key="key">
    <span v-html="item"></span>
  </option>

</div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Desc by what property? Create an computed property that returns a new array with the sorted `data` values.

Comment: @test To clarify, you want the number words to be ordered by their numeric value? Or did you just want alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1):

What you try to achieve is sorting an object structure in a descending order, by key, which is a numeric value of the equivalent word.

First, you should probably find a library which converts textual words to numbers. In the bellow example, I have chosen [words-to-numbers](https://github.com/finnfiddle/words-to-numbers).

Then, you have to sort each [key, value] pairs of your object, depending on the numeric value you get from the word conversion.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <option v-for="[key, item] in orderedData" :value="key" v-bind:key="key">
    <span v-html="item"></span>
  </option>
</div>
```

```js
import wordsToNumbers from 'words-to-numbers';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    data: {
      One: "One",
      Three: "Three",
      Five: "Five"
    }
  },

  computed: {
    orderedData() {
      return Object.entries(this.data).sort((a, b) => {
        return  wordsToNumbers(b[0].toLowerCase()) - wordsToNumbers(a[0].toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It works, but it sorts based on the key. Is there a way I can sort using values?

Comment: Can you give an example of a more complex input and what output you expect?

Comment: Updated answer based on what you ask in the question title.